# Springboot security configuration issue

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am in the development of a project for my professional practice of my university studies which consists of developing a website for a small company in my city, and as I am currently a beginner in development, I thought it appropriate to use a framework with which I am more familiar (practically the only one xd) which is the Springboot.

The project consists of the development of a web page of the company, the typical page where the company information is displayed as "About us" and "Contact" information where you add your data and a message and the information reaches the company (This because the small company is a distributor of computer products and would like to contact them and manage orders more effectively), this frontend I implemented it in "index.html".

That is the initial and 'easy' part of the page, but in addition to that, he told me that he would like to implement an order tracking section, where customers who have already purchased a shipment can see information about their order by entering the corresponding OC code that is given to them at the time of payment, I implemented this front end in "tracking.html".

The idea I had in mind was the next, when accessing the url of the page show the information corresponding to the company as contact and information in "index.html", and in the navbar add the tracking section "tracking.html" where customers can access and place the OC code.

But in order to be able to see this order data on behalf of the customers, it is necessary to be able to register the corresponding OC Code and add the respective tracking information in the database so that the customer can see it, this obviously by the employee. Therefore, in the same page of "tracking.html", I added a section that redirects the user to a "login.html" where employees can log in to update or modify the database something like an intranet, (although customers can also access the login, what I did was to register the user directly from the backend so that there is only one and can be used by people who have such data).

So far so good, the problem arises next. The SpringBoot security configuration asks that in the `.loginPage()` method to assign what is the login page, if I put "login.html" the system works correctly and reads the user data created without error and logs in with them. The problem of this is that as I said, this page is intended for the general public, the idea is that when they access the url, they load "index.html" with the information of the company and thus leave the login as something hidden and secondary only for employees, but if I add the login method: `.loginPage(/login)`, this causes that when accessing the url ALWAYS send me initially to the login page. Which for the general public would be a bit annoying and confusing.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                "/css/**",
                "/img/**",
                "/js/**",
                "/lib/**",
                "/scss/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/home/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        **.loginPage("/login")**
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .clearAuthentication(true)
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/limit");
    }
```

What I tried after this, was to remove the /login from the method and leave the index as follows: `.loginPage(/)`. This way when I access the url as general public, now it sends me to the home page with the information, but now there is another problem, and is that when accessing the tracking section and then the login, if I put the user data created for inventory management, I get the following error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:253)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1261)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```

What I had in mind and how I wanted it to work, is that as a CUSTOMER when accessing the url of the page this will take you to the index and show you the contact information of the company, and when accessing the tracking section place the OC code and see the information corresponding to my order.

And as an EMPLOYEE, what I wanted is that when accessing the url also shows me the home page with the information, and when accessing the tracking section to access the login from there and log in with the administrator user to manage orders stored on the website and so customers can see their data (something like an intranet integrated into the page).

I hope someone can help me with this problem, because what I start to believe is that maybe SpringBoot is not the most suitable for the development of a project of this style and I should use another software, but I don't have so much time for this and it's the only one I know :(